# ESTA application when place of birth and citizenship aren’t the same

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I have to complete the ESTA application and I have a few question regarding the country of birth...

So I'm entering the USA with my Korean passport; however, I was born in Paraguay and so I also have a Paraguayan passport. However, my Korean passport just says that my citizenship Korean, so I would like to know if I would  have problems getting the VWP in case I travel with my Korean passport?

Comment: I assume, like all the contributors who answered, you have a South Korean passport. Otherwise, no VWP for you.

Comment: As I remember, the application form asks for a list of all other passports you have or had (even expired ones).

Answer (score 19):

Answer the questions as they're written.
If you're asked for your country of birth, give your country of birth.
Having a passport from some other country doesn't change your country of birth, and this is not a particularly uncommon circumstance - there are many people who have a passport from a country other than the one they were born in.
Since you are not a citizen of, nor were you born in, [one of the countries which are specifically excluded from using the VWP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq), having different citizenship to where you were born is not a problem.

Comment: What if the other country is Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan?

Comment: @phoog In that case, answer the questions *not* as they're written... (???) The message is "Always answer forms as asked. If there is space for clarification, add it (which there is none in this case). If rejected, apply for regular visa. Never lie."

Comment: @FooBar I was reacting to the statement "having different citizenship to where you were born is not a problem" which is the only part of this answer that seems to respond to the question "I would like to know if I would have problems getting the VWP," and which at best does not address that issue completely.

Comment: @phoog so where's the problem? The problem you're pointing out isn't "having different citizenship to where you were born", the problem you're pointing out is having a citizenship or a birthplace which might be problematic **on its own**.

Comment: @Beanluc The question (as it stood when I left that comment) asked whether there could be a problem applying for ESTA, given certain circumstances which (at the time of the comment in question) included being born in and having the nationality of an *unspecified* other country.  Given that the country was not specified, there was indeed a potential problem depending on the identity of the unspecified country, and this answer failed to mention that potential problem.

Comment: @Beanluc If someone asked about timing a Schengen short-stay visa application between their return from an 89-day stay in France and their departure a month later for an 89-day stay in Spain, should the answer avoid mentioning the fact that such a visa application would necessarily be refused just because the question didn't ask specifically about that?

Answer (score 8):

> I would like to know if I would have problems getting the VWP in case I travel with my Korean passport.

It depends on which other country you are a citizen of.  A few years ago, the VWP was changed such that those who hold a VWP-eligible passport who also have the nationality of either Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan are [ineligible to use the VWP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq):

> Under the Act, travelers in the following categories are no longer eligible to travel or be admitted to the United States, without a waiver, under the VWP:
>
> - Nationals of VWP countries who have traveled to or been present in Iraq, Syria, Iran, Sudan, Libya, Somalia, or Yemen at any time on or after March 1, 2011 (with limited exceptions); and
> - Nationals of VWP countries who are also nationals of Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan.

Otherwise, holding a passport from a country whose nationals aren't eligible for the VWP (such as Paraguay) does not disqualify you from the VWP.

Comment: This answer is ambiguous. OP asks whether it makes a difference to apply for ESTA with one of multiple passports. This answer sounds like it "*depends*". The reality is that it does not: Whether one of the countries of citizenship is barred from VWP or not, it never makes a difference under which of the two passports one applues: If one is banned, the application will get rejected irregardless of which passport is used. If none is banned, the application will be accepted irregardless of which passport is used.

Comment: @FooBar the question is whether OP "would have problems getting the VWP", and the answer is quite clearly that it *does* depend on what other passport OP holds.  It's not even possible to *submit* an application using a passport from Iran, Iraq, Syria, or Sudan.  On the other hand, it's also not possible to submit an application using a Nigerian passport, but a dual national of Korea and Nigeria *can* get ESTA with a Korean passport.

Comment: @FooBar The asker clearly says that they're applying for an ESTA using their Korean passport details. As such, the only thing that matters about the other passport is whether it's from one of the four countries that disqualify you from VWP.

Comment: The question has now been clarified: the other citizenship is Paraguay.

Comment: Not in all countries you are automatically a citizen in, or stay that way,  because you were born there

Comment: @PlasmaHH that is correct.  But from the question as posed, we can infer that GCPO is a citizen of the country of birth, because the question said "I have been born in another country and so I have another pasport."

Comment: I was referring to your statement "It depends on which country you were born in, since you are also a citizen of that country." which doesn't refer to his statement, thus making it sound like it is a generic one.

Comment: @PlasmaHH that is also correct.  I made that statement in the context of the question, but for the general case that would indeed have been an unwarranted conclusion.  I think I started the sentence that way because I was planning to write that being born in one of the 4 countries disqualifies one from the VWP, but then I checked a couple of sources that suggest that this isn't the case.  I've changed it to something a bit more straightforward now; thanks for pointing it out.